# Is there a way to transform scale without stretching an Object Fit?

Tags: css, css-transforms, object-fit

If I am using a transform scale is there a way to keep the object fit image using cover from stretching?
Here is my code

```
div.category {
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    object-fit:cover;
}

div.category:hover {
  transform:scalex(1.2)
}
```

html

```
<div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Elephant-dusting674.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Bananas-and-kiwi-221.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x950&text=1200x950+-+Category+3+-" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle explaining what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/n1x5ak2t/

I would love if the image just scaled up to fit the new div width without distorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a different animation. Here is an idea using `clip-path`

```css
div.category {
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.35s;
  clip-path:inset(0 10%);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

div.category:hover {
  clip-path:inset(0 0%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="category">
    <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Elephant-dusting674.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Bananas-and-kiwi-221.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x950&text=1200x950+-+Category+3+-" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh this is clean! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach.

```css
div.category {
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    object-fit: cover;
}

div.category:hover {
  transform:scalex(1.2)
}
div.category:hover img {
  transform:scale(1.2)
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Elephant-dusting674.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Bananas-and-kiwi-221.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x950&text=1200x950+-+Category+3+-" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
div.category:hover img {
  transform:scalex(1.2)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7d31Ln0f/

Comment: That just stretches the image. I want to actually stretch the div wider without stretching the image

Comment: did you try the fiddle?

Comment: I tried it. It actually inspired me to do 
```
div.category:hover {
  transform:scalex(1.2)
}

div.category:hover img {
  transform:scale(1.2)
}
```

Comment: If you wanna scale the div with the image, you have 2 conflicting css properties:
- `object-fit:cover;`
- `transform:scalex(1.2) `
you probably wanna use `scale(1,2)`, not `scalex` to preserve the aspect ratio